# How can i make my C++ code buildable with clang on Mac?

Tags: c++, gcc, clang

I have a bunch of .cpp and .c files and i use gcc/make to build a project. On Mac there is only gcc 4.2. It is very old and puts a lot of limitations on the language. I've heard clang is the default compiler for Mac. How can i change my makefiles to use clang?

Comment: If it is an issue with the version of GCC, you could consider installing a newer version. I got GCC 4.7 from macports.org without any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try replacing CC=g++ with CC=clang in you makefiles or doing 
CC=clang make instead of make
and see if it compiles.

If you use gnu c/c++ extensions or gcc command line options it may not compile, in that case you can try googling for help.

Comment: Should i use any special compiler switches for clang?

Comment: I don't have much experience with clang(outside of building it from source once so that I could compile stuff on embeded linux board). If there isn't any specific reason for it, I can't think of what default flags other then -Wall to enable warnings.

Comment: what flags do you use for gcc? are any of them incompatible?

Answer (score 3):

For starters, GCC 4.2 is not "very old and puts a lot of limitations on the language."

That being said, your Mac, if it has GCC 4.2 installed, should also have `clang` installed.  Xcode includes both clang and GCC (built with LLVM), as `clang` and `gcc`/`g++` respectively.  Either:

- change your makefiles to point to `clang` directly
- set the `CC` environment variable to `clang`
- soft link `g++` to `clang` if you want to be really hamfisted about it.

Any one should do the trick.

Comment: For a 500k LOC project it is.

Comment: @TonyPerez: plenty of us building multi-million line projects with `g++`.  Has support for most of TR1 and can build boost…unclear exactly how broken you can really consider it - yes, clang has *other* features, but that wasn't the assertion.

Comment: Using g++ 4.1.2 on multi millions LOC projects and doesn't have problems with that. I guess size doesn't matter.

Comment: GCC 4.2 is in fact very old.

Comment: @MarcusJ: obviously, this answer is 3 years old.